# What data is still left after factory reset?

Tags: security, factory-reset

I have an unlocked Xiaomi Poco X3 (surya) and I got banned in [Jodel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tellm.android.app&hl=de&gl=US). The app doesn't have many permissions, but somehow the App recognize me even after a factory reset.
On every new instance I only create a new Google Account and Download the app.
I tried:

- Wipe everything in TWRP
- Fastboot flash with [this](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui/surya/stable/V12.5.3.0.RJGMIXM/)
- Spoof MAC Address with Root
- Use VPN

Which data remains on the device after flashing and wiping everyhing I could?

How could an app recognize you after all this?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I assume Jodel simply recognizes that the device is unlocked. Then it have to recognize your device, it simply recognizes that the device is not in a genuine state and denies to run.

Comment: @alecxs the phone has no SIM-Card inside.

Comment: @Robert Can apps recognize that the phone is unlocked? Safety Net etc. passed. The phone is not rooted just unlocked.
On my other phone which is unlocked and rooted the app runs fine.

Comment: https://jodel.com/app/de/login-erklaerung-android

Comment: @alecxs yes I read the page already, however I found this in their Privacy Police: "We store unique identifier of blocked users for a period of 18 months to ensure that these blocked users cannot open a new account on their respective mobile device. The legal basis for such processing is Art. 6 (1) lit. f GDPR (legitimate interests; the legitimate interest in using these data results from the fact that access to the App is not possible without these data)."
Unfortunately, they don't write which data they use exactly.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silverlab.app.deviceidchanger.free